# ¿En SQL no usar AS es una mala práctica? ¿Por qué? ¿Está documentado en alguna parte?

Tags: sql, buenas-prácticas

Leí (si mal no recuerdo en un post o un comentario a una pregunta en Stackoverflow en inglés) que en SQL no usar `AS` para los alias era una mala práctica.

Yo suelo usar mis consultas sin `AS` cuando son alias, porque me parece más elegante, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla t1 INNER JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
SELECT MAX(id)  mayor FROM tabla ...
```

En vez de:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tabla AS t1 INNER JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
SELECT MAX(id)  AS mayor FROM tabla ...
```

Estuve mirando por ejemplo en el [Manual de Referencia de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) y no encontré nada que diga de forma explícita que no usar `AS` sea una mala práctica.

En resumen, quiero saber si no usar `AS` es una mala práctica. Si lo es, ¿por qué lo es y donde está documentado?

La pregunta se refiere a SQL en general, no a manejadores específicos.

Comment: Si esto no está documentado o es difícil hallar información al respecto, ¿Las respuestas no estarían basadas en opiniones?

Comment: @MauricioContreras yo busco una respuesta de alguien que conozca el tema más a fondo dado que no he encontrado documentación oficial al respecto.

Comment: Por ahora, lo único que podría darte, es una opinión. Ser más explicito a la hora de escribir código, tiene sus beneficios. Para `from tabla1 tabla2` ¿que es `tabla2`? ¿un alías de `tabla1` o un `join` implícito al que le falta una coma? Con el `as` hay mucha menos ambigüedad.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho en el ejemplo expuesto en la pregunta `FROM tabla1 t1 INNER JOIN ...`, `t1` sería un alias de `tabla1` Estuve viendo si encontraba el estándar de SQL, no sé si existe ni donde consultarlo, por si dice algo sobre el tema ¿?

Comment: Tu buena práctica de usar `JOINS` explícitos sin duda te evita el error que te mencioné, que es el único motivo por el cual (entiendo yo) el `AS` tiene una influencia positiva. El estándar que encontré es el del 92, por si te sirve: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: El estándar existe ISO/IEC 9075-1:2016, https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9075:-1:ed-5:v1:en. pero está difícil encontrarlo en PDF por la web.

Comment: El uso de *`as`* es opcional, de acuerdo al estándar. Algunos autores y personas te dirán que es mejor no usarlo, otros te dirán que es mejor usarlo. Yo estoy con vos, padre, en que las consultas son más elegantes sin el `as`, que me parece que está de más y las hace demasiado verbosas. A mi no me confunde para nada ni me hace falta, ni me sobra.

Answer (score 6):

El estándar ISO/IEC 9075 en la especificación de query indica que:

---

> **7.12 < query specification >**
>
> This Subclause is modified by Subclause 7.1,“”,
>   in ISO/IEC 9075-4.
>
> **Function**
>
> Specify a table derived from the result of a .
>
> **Format**
>
> ```
> < query specification > ::=
>   SELECT [ < set quantifier > ] < select list >< table expression >
>
> < select list > ::= < asterisk > | < select sublist > [ { < comma >< select sublist > }... ]
>
> < select sublist > ::=< derived column > | < qualified asterisk >
>
> < qualified asterisk > ::= < asterisked identifier chain >< period >< asterisk > | < all fields reference >
>
> < asterisked identifier chain > ::= < asterisked identifier> [ { < period >< asterisked identifier > }... ]
>
> < asterisked identifier > ::=< identifier >
>
> < derived column > ::= < value expression > [ < as clause > ] 
>
> < as clause > ::= [ AS ] < column name >
>
> < all fields reference > ::= < value expression primary >< period >< asterisk > [ AS < left paren >< all fields column name list >< right paren > ]
>
> < all fields column name list > ::= < column name list >
> ```

---

Nos interesa:

```
 < as clause > ::= [ AS ] < column name >
```

Si se interpreta la documentación como de costumbre, los corchetes indican que es opcional lo que remarcan por lo cual la palabra `AS` para indicar el alias de la columna es opcional bajo la especificación.

Sé que en la pregunta hablamos de tablas pero no creo que difieran en éste concepto.

No creo que sea mala práctica dejarlo sin el `AS`, apostaría a que ha quedado así por temas de compatibilidad.

Dejo el enlace al borrador del estándar que encontré en la web (Página 377):
http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N1801-1850/32N1822T-text_for_ballot-CD_9075-2.pdf

Comment: Tu respuesta da tu opinión, pero no lleva a algún documento, o estilo de programación en que se considere canónicamente buena o mala práctica